# Basic Excel VBA turns number lock off, I've no idea why

Tags: excel, vba, num-lock

This is the code that I use regularly fired from a Button (Form Control) that is stored in PERSONAL.XLSB and therefore available universally on this PC.

```
Sub Today()

    Dim Today As Date
    
    Today = Date
    
    ActiveCell.Value = Today
    
    Application.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    
End Sub
```

Immediately after using that button the number lock is turned off.

Comment: I have no clue how SendKeys could change the NUM-Lock, but why are you using `SendKeys` anyhow? If you want to select the next cell, use `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select`

Comment: I'm using SendKeys because that's the first thing Google suggested and I'm no good at VBA, but I just tried your suggestion and it doesn't cause Num Lock to turn off, so I'm now using that.  Many thanks Thomas.  I won't marked this as Answered just yet as I'm still curious, but I'll do that is a couple of hours if no one can answer the question.

Comment: Seems a long way around, to enter the current date I use ctrl+; and for time I use cmnd+; - equivalent shortcuts exist on pc...

Comment: It is a known side effect of using sendkeys.

Comment: @Storax Yes, that does answer it!  Known issue indeed, also shows I need to work harder at finding known issues before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue. You could try using shell's SendKeys instead:

```
Sub Today()

    Dim Today As Date
    
    Today = Date
    
    ActiveCell.Value = Today

    Dim WshShell As Object            
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}", True
    
End Sub
```

However, as FunThomas points out in comments - there are better ways of manipulating the 'cursor'.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've marked your comment as Answered, but I'm using FunThomas' answer.